# Jquery ui Append not working resizable

Tags: jquery

'm studying jquery and I came across an issue

I have a div that is resizable and want to add another inside dynamically through a button, but I want this next is also resizable, so I'm using the same class.

but is not working

another div to appear, however it is not resizable

```
    <div id="row" class="ui-widget-content">
        <div id="bot_add">X</div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#row')
                    .draggable()
                     .resizable({
            stop: function(e, ui) {
            var temp = $('#row').css('width');
            alert(temp);
        }
    });

$('#bot_add').live('click', function(){

    $('#row').append("<div id='row' class='ui-widget-content'></div>");

});



});
    </script>
```

sorry my bad english, I'm brazilian

Comment: You applied `resizable()` to your initial `div` and then you added the new `div` on `click()` -- this new `div` has not had `resizable()` applied to it.

Comment: BTW IDs must be UNIQUE use class="row" instead of id

Comment: class doesnt work to is not that roasted

Comment: David, i figured out that but how i solve this

Comment: @CaioSchiavo  Are you the OP? Class works but you need to use the right selector $('.row') not $('#row')

Comment: @roasted i've already change the selector

Answer (score 0):

As you are adding element dynamically - Try this way

```
$('body').on("mouseenter", "ui-widget-content", function(e) {
    var target = $(e.target);
    if (target.data("resizable")) return;
    target.resizable({
        stop: function(e, ui) {
           var temp = $('#row').css('width');
           alert(temp);
         }
    });
});
```

As [@roasted](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1414562/roasted) mentioned , your `id='row'` is going to be duplicate, use class instead

Comment: There is no object body, there is a tag body: $('body')

Comment: @Mohammad Adil, tkx but i got an error #<object> has no method .delegate

Comment: What version of jQuery you are using ?

Comment: Why not the latest version ?

Comment: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js ... This is latest version

Comment: tkx again Mohammad but still not working, i'll try a little more here